# Is there a min and max zoom that can be set on a Kendo chart? My chart upon zooming out makes category axis label illegible due to many items

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo Angular chart component on which i need to set a minimum zoom so that after a point, zooming out is not an option, otherwise the category axis labels become illegible to read. Similarily, I want to set a max zoom as well. You can see the chart issue in the gif.

Using drive because the file size is > 2 Mb, and stack overflow doesn't allow that.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOXLmnCgOIUb7fVT5pkQ6lbWb8IvAxhK/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `zoom` event. You can't check what the zoom level is but you can check what the viewing range is and prevent the zoom action if the range exceeds your preference.

Let's say the categories are number and you want to see 20 categories at most.

Here are the main points to accomplish what you want to do:

1. Name your category axis:

   ```
   public categoryAxis: any = {
       min: 10,
       max: 20,
       name: "test"
   };
   ```
2. Add the event handler to the `kendo-chart` component:

   ```
   (zoom)=zoomHandler($event)
   ```
3. Add the event handler function to the component:

   ```
   public zoomHandler(e) {
       console.log("zoom", e);

       // Prevent the zoom action if the axis range is greater than 20 (in this example, the categories are numbers)
       if (e.axisRanges.test.max - e.axisRanges.test.min > 20) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   }
   ```

You can see an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jz8npi).

Comment: Thanks a lot @shai. If you could, could you also look at this other problem I'm having?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676975/scrolling-issue-with-kendo-chart-on-mobile