# Scrolling issue with kendo chart on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, jquery-mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have multiple kendo charts with panning and zooming enabled. On the mobile view, each graph takes up 100% width and since panning and zooming is enabled, the touch events are not fired and hence, no scrolling up or down in mobile. I tried attaching an event handler but to no avail. I want to enable browser touch events when the touch event fires from somewhere other than the chart area (legends or blank spaces) as highlighted in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was able to fix it by overriding the `k-chart-surface` `touch-action`, from **none** to **auto**

```
.k-chart-surface {
  touch-action: auto !important;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

"The **touch-action** CSS property sets how an element's region can be manipulated by a touchscreen user (for example, by zooming features built into the browser)."

Hope it helps you,
Regards